# How to get notified when the iPad keyboard disappears?

Tags: ipad, ios

On the iPad, the user can press a "keyboard away" button that lets it go away. This button won't trigger the didEndOnExit event we're used to for resigning the first responder status of the responsible text input view.

How can I hook up to this even when the user presses the keyboard away button? It's an universal binary, btw.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can subscribe your class to the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification notification, which is posted immediately prior to the dismissal of the keyboard.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

See also

```
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
```

Answer (score 2):

The UIControlEventEditingDidEnd event is for when the "go away" button is pressed (bot not for when the done button is pressed. This is UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit)